# How to call a function on window resize

Tags: jquery

I need to load a function on window resize while also taking effect at a certain breakpoint.  I'm using it to hide specific classes when viewed on a mobile sized screen.

I've seen a couple of similar questions on here but I'm unsure how to combine them with my breakpoint code.

```
if($(window).width() < 767)  {
    $('header#articles-insight nav').removeClass('collapsed');
    $('button.menu-toggle').removeClass('collapsed');
}
```

This was the working code guys:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
       $('header#articles-insight nav').removeClass('collapsed');
       $('button.menu-toggle').removeClass('collapsed');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please share the code and progress you have made so far.

Comment: See this [this link](https://api.jquery.com/resize/). sample code could be  `$( window ).resize(function() { // your code here});`

Comment: Ivan Minakov's answer worked but the only problem now is that the class hides ONLY while I'm actively resizing the window.  What other function would I need to add to this so that the class would stay permanently hidden?

Comment: Thanks Shourav!  That worked perfectly.